# Netty throws java.nio.channels.ClosedSelectorException on android-x86

Tags: android, nio, netty, android-x86

I'am trying to use [android-x86](http://android-x86.org) instead standard android-emulator, because it's very FAST. Launched it via virtualbox with image android-x86-2.2-generic.iso.

My project using netty and then I'am trying to create connection got the follow error:

> 06-22 13:15:10.600: WARN/lientSocketPipelineSink(2411): Unexpected exception in the      selector loop.
>   06-22 13:15:10.600: WARN/lientSocketPipelineSink(2411): java.nio.channels.ClosedSelectorException
>   06-22 13:15:10.600: WARN/lientSocketPipelineSink(2411):     at org.apache.harmony.nio.internal.SelectorImpl.closeCheck(SelectorImpl.java:204)
>   06-22 13:15:10.600: WARN/lientSocketPipelineSink(2411):     at org.apache.harmony.nio.internal.SelectorImpl.selectInternal(SelectorImpl.java:236)
>   06-22 13:15:10.600: WARN/lientSocketPipelineSink(2411):     at org.apache.harmony.nio.internal.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:224)
>   06-22 13:15:10.600: WARN/lientSocketPipelineSink(2411):     at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink$Boss.run(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:239)
>   06-22 13:15:10.600: WARN/lientSocketPipelineSink(2411):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
>   06-22 13:15:10.600: WARN/lientSocketPipelineSink(2411):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
>   06-22 13:15:10.600: WARN/lientSocketPipelineSink(2411):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should use OIO instead of NIO because of the known issue: http://markmail.org/message/ypa3nrr64kzsyfsa

Comment: Thanks! I switched to OioClientSocketChannelFactory and all works fine!